# Is there a good approach for adding activity switching code via button click to a map activity in Kotlin?

Tags: android, kotlin, user-interface, maps, arcgis

I am playing with the ArcGIS map SDK to write a Kotlin program using Android Studio. I have a demo program with the map code running. When I attempt to add in my activity switching code using button onClickListeners, the program will crash on launch (emulator or target device). I have tested my activity switching code blocks in a separate project in the same onCreate function, and it works perfectly. I am curious if it is a conflict between the map bindings and activity intents, but I feel there is something fundamental I am missing here.

Even though I am aware of fragmentation and viewpager, I thought activity switching via button widgets was simple for me to understand in comparison to working with fragments, so that is why I took this approach. Besides my specific question with the code, if you have suggestions for working with UI controls over a map interface, and integrating these controls with other activity pages, I would appreciate your input. Thank you

```
package com.example.app

import android.content.Intent
import android.os.Bundle
import android.widget.Button
import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity
import androidx.databinding.DataBindingUtil
import com.arcgismaps.ApiKey
import com.arcgismaps.ArcGISEnvironment
import com.arcgismaps.mapping.ArcGISMap
import com.arcgismaps.mapping.BasemapStyle
import com.arcgismaps.mapping.Viewpoint
import com.arcgismaps.mapping.view.MapView
import com.example.app.databinding.ActivityMapsBinding

class MapsActivity : AppCompatActivity() {

    private val activityMapsBinding: ActivityMapsBinding by lazy {
        DataBindingUtil.setContentView(this, R.layout.activity_maps)
    }

    private val mapView: MapView by lazy {
        activityMapsBinding.mapView
    }

    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)

        lifecycle.addObserver(mapView)

        // call the API key setup function
        setApiKey()

        // call the map setup function
        setupMap()

        // listen for button clicks to switch between activity screens.
        val buttonClickSettings = findViewById<Button>(R.id.settings_activity_button)
        buttonClickSettings.setOnClickListener {
            val intent = Intent(this, SettingsActivity::class.java)
            startActivity(intent)
        }

        val buttonClickFly = findViewById<Button>(R.id.fly_activity_button)
        buttonClickFly.setOnClickListener {
            val intent = Intent(this, FlyActivity::class.java)
            startActivity(intent)
        }

    }

    private fun setupMap() {
        // variable for ArcGIS map default style
        val map = ArcGISMap(BasemapStyle.ArcGISTopographic)

        // set the map to be displayed in the layout's MapView
        mapView.map = map

        // set the default location and zoom to display on the map.
        mapView.setViewpoint(Viewpoint(52.1200, -120.0000, 90000.0))
    }

    private fun setApiKey() {
        // Not ideal to have the API key in source code, but will do for now.
        ArcGISEnvironment.apiKey = ApiKey.create("")
    }

}
```

Comment: Hello I suggest you to use buttons from binding first and then check your activity layouts if they are correctly created or not. Also If you can edit your question with showing an information about your error, it would be better for us to understand the problem.